# npm version to add alpha postfix

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

#### How can i bump the `package.json` version to contain `-alpha` using npm versioning.

Running `npm version <new version>` will bump the version of the `package.json` file, however i want to add `-alpha` postfix to the version, but i am unable to as it is not stated in the documentation, but its supported by semver itself.

**Actual Result:**

```
> npm version prerelease
> v0.2.1-1
```

**Expected Result:**

```
> v0.2.1-alpha
```

Comment: Exactly my question! Fingers crossed for an answer :)

Comment: @DaveKerr i submitted a pull request for it on npm, https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/13794

Comment: What's the latest on this? I have this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846170/how-to-generate-npm-release-candidate-version

Comment: Shouldn't you just edit the version field in your package.json file? Try adding "-alpha" after the prerelease command modifier?

Comment: @jwdonahue that might work, but IMO npm should provide this functionality since it is part of semver spec.

Comment: SemVer does not define any prerelease tags. The fact that you are trying to create one without specifying the tag to use, is probably prompting NPM to use the default value, which appears to be a counter.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You cannot set `0.2.1-alpha` automatically, but `0.2.1-alpha.0` is possible.

[`npm version` supports a `--preid`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) option to specify the prefix of prereleases. It's available in combination with `pre*` versions.

**Example 1.** Make the alpha of next major version:

```bash
# 1.2.3 => 2.0.0-alpha.0
npm version premajor --preid alpha
```

**Example 2.** Bump alpha to beta:

```bash
# 2.0.0-alpha.0 => 2.0.0-beta.0
npm version prerelease --preid beta
```

Once you create a prerelease, you can increment the number using `prerelease` argument.

```bash
# 2.0.0-beta.0 => 2.0.0-beta.1
npm version prerelease
```

Comment: I would like to point out that you also need to add the 'alpha' or 'beta' tag when publishing, like this: `npm publish --tag alpha` to have your package marked as such on npmjs.com and "withheld" from automatic installation

Comment: If you are using this in a repository that is mid-way through a bunch of alpha changes but hasn't been using git tags or `npm version` so far I found it useful to first create a fixed version & tag via say `npm version 2.0.0-alpha.5`, then you can run `npm version prerelease` to go from `2.0.0-alpha.5 -> 2.0.0-alpha.6`

Answer (score 10):

While -alpha and -beta are common prerelease tags, they are not defined by SemVer. -alpha.1, -alpha.2, -beta.1, etc, are also fairly common. The spec defines the prerelease tag as a series of dot separated alphanumeric or numeric character fields. The SemVer spec uses alpha and beta in some examples, but they are not defined by the spec. NPM has no way of knowing what tag you want to use if you do not tell it. It apparently defaults to numeric prerelease tag, which makes some sense, since SemVer allows that (-1, -2, -3 provides all the necessary semantics).

The NPM documentation sucks and I have fortunately never had to use NPM. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version. Especially:

> The newversion argument should be a valid semver string, a valid second argument to [semver.inc](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#functions) (one of patch, minor, major, prepatch, preminor, premajor, prerelease), or from-git.

Looking at the provided link (https://github.com/npm/node-semver#functions), they seem to be referring to increasing the specified version field. In the absence of the alpha tag on the version string in the package.json file, it makes a lot of sense that it would append the missing numeric prerelease tag as -1.

I just tested this theory with:

```
> echo Test > test.txt
> npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (packageTest)
version: (1.0.0) 0.1.0-alpha.0
description: Test package.
entry point: (index.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to D:\TMP\Joseph\packageTest\package.json:

{
  "name": "packageTest",
  "version": "0.1.0-alpha.0",
  "description": "Test package.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}


Is this ok? (yes)

> npm version prerelease
v0.1.0-alpha.1

> cat package.json
{
  "name": "packageTest",
  "version": "0.1.0-alpha.1",
  "description": "Test package.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

As expected.